# San Francisco font not showing in apple watch simulator

Tags: iphone, fonts, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I installed San Francisco Font in my iMac [image: San Francisco Font in my iMac] as well as I have listed it in my project application [image: San Francisco Font in my Xcode project] [image].
  When I am running my application the font is not showing in Apple Watch Simulator . Please help me what I am doing wrong , why it's not showing in Apple Watch Simulator .[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic notification interface doesn't support using anything other than the system font styles and weights. This means you have to use something like "Body" instead of specifying San Francisco explicitly – even if it *is* the system font.